# Volume of toric conjugacy class

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $M/\mathbb{Q}$ an imaginary quadratic extension. Let $T_{M,p}$ be the torus in $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ arising from $M$ and $C_{M,p}$ an open subset in $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ consisting of elements conjugate to elements in the torus $T_{M,p}$. Let $\mu$ be the Haar measure on $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ normalised so that the volume of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ equals one. What is the volume of the open subset $C_{M,p}$? It seems to be less than half.